Hive on Tez insert data fail at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 95
hive> insert into music values (1,'Faded');

Query ID = hadoopusr_20240625144523_fccb44c9-00e4-4a79-9d81-b5d56517a67d
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Tez session was closed. Reopening...
Session re-established.
Session re-established.
Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_1719298365779_0022)

    VERTICES      MODE        STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED


Map 1            container  INITIALIZING     -1          0        0       -1       0       0
Reducer 2        container        INITED      1          0        0        1       0       0
VERTICES: 00/02  [>>--------------------------] 0%    ELAPSED TIME: 0.47 s
Status: Failed
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1719298365779_0022_1_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1719298365779_0022_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: _dummy_table initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1719298365779_0022_1_00 [Map 1], java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load plan: hdfs://mycluster/tmp/hive/hadoopusr/4d22385a-3fd2-4415-b8d5-eb89b008a383/hive_2024-06-25_14-45-23_381_614477188207444564-1/hadoopusr/_tez_scratch_dir/5f3e5d69-a7b2-4bc0-80ea-d487897cbc30/map.xml
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getBaseWork(Utilities.java:502)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getMapWork(Utilities.java:335)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.init(HiveInputFormat.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getSplits(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:508)
at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.hadoop.MRInputHelpers.generateOldSplits(MRInputHelpers.java:485)
at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.hadoop.MRInputHelpers.generateInputSplitsToMem(MRInputHelpers.java:334)
at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.common.MRInputAMSplitGenerator.initialize(MRInputAMSplitGenerator.java:121)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:281)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:272)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:272)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:256)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:108)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:41)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:77)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 95
Serialization trace:
conf (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator)
aliasToWork (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:137)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:670)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readClass(SerializationUtilities.java:185)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:118)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readClassAndObject(SerializationUtilities.java:180)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:161)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:39)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:218)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:686)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:210)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializeObjectByKryo(SerializationUtilities.java:729)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializePlan(SerializationUtilities.java:613)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializePlan(SerializationUtilities.java:590)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getBaseWork(Utilities.java:463)
... 19 more
]
Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1719298365779_0022_1_01, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in INITED state., Vertex vertex_1719298365779_0022_1_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1719298365779_0022_1_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1719298365779_0022_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: _dummy_table initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1719298365779_0022_1_00 [Map 1], java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load plan: hdfs://mycluster/tmp/hive/hadoopusr/4d22385a-3fd2-4415-b8d5-eb89b008a383/hive_2024-06-25_14-45-23_381_614477188207444564-1/hadoopusr/_tez_scratch_dir/5f3e5d69-a7b2-4bc0-80ea-d487897cbc30/map.xml
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getBaseWork(Utilities.java:502)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getMapWork(Utilities.java:335)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.init(HiveInputFormat.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getSplits(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:508)
at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.hadoop.MRInputHelpers.generateOldSplits(MRInputHelpers.java:485)
at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.hadoop.MRInputHelpers.generateInputSplitsToMem(MRInputHelpers.java:334)
at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.common.MRInputAMSplitGenerator.initialize(MRInputAMSplitGenerator.java:121)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:281)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:272)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:272)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:256)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:108)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:41)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:77)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 95
Serialization trace:
conf (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator)
aliasToWork (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:137)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:670)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readClass(SerializationUtilities.java:185)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:118)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readClassAndObject(SerializationUtilities.java:180)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:161)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:39)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:218)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:686)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:210)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializeObjectByKryo(SerializationUtilities.java:729)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializePlan(SerializationUtilities.java:613)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializePlan(SerializationUtilities.java:590)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getBaseWork(Utilities.java:463)
... 19 more
]Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1719298365779_0022_1_01, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in INITED state., Vertex vertex_1719298365779_0022_1_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1
===================================================================================================
When I uses MR as hive.execution.engine, everything work fine. When I use Tez as engine and select query like order by , join and others, it work. But when I insert something with Tez engine in beeline or hive cli, I got above error. My Hadoop is 3.4.0, Hive is 3.1.3 and Tez is 0.10.2 and OS is RHEL 7.9. And hdfs://mycluster/tmp/hive/hadoopusr/4d22385a-3fd2-4415-b8d5-eb89b008a383/hive_2024-06-25_14-45-23_381_614477188207444564-1/hadoopusr/_tez_scratch_dir/5f3e5d69-a7b2-4bc0-80ea-d487897cbc30/map.xml this dir doesn't even exist. I think it because of serialization / deserialization problem. Please help me. I am stuck with this error more than a week.
I find many site and same problem and try many solution, but didn't work.

The issue is caused by a version mismatch between the Hadoop and Tez jars. I got the same error after upgrading my Hadoop version to 3.4.0. I am using Hive 3.1.2 and Tez 0.10.2.
To resolve this, navigate to the 'tez/shared/' folder, where you will find a 'tez.tar.gz' file. Extract the file and go to the '/lib' directory. Replace the jars that are related to the new Hadoop version. You can find the related Hadoop jar files in 'hadoop/share/hadoop' directory. After that, recreate the tez.tar.gz file with the updated jars and delete the old one. Finally, copy the new tar file to the HDFS directory. Restart the Hadoop and Hive services including Hive metastore service.
